# Checking connection in wire bondings

Tags: wire

I'm doing an assignment where I want create a setup to test wire connections in X-ray detector sensors. There are about 250 wires between this sensor and the control PCB. I want to test the connection in each of these 250 wires.

The ultimate goal is to put them for a temperature cycling test, and display on which cycles the wires are broken.

What would be the best way to inspect if there's connection in each of these 250 wires? Simply put, I want to know if every wires are still working.

Comment: Can you exite your sensor and verify that it is providing the expected stimulus to the circuits on the PCB?

Comment: If one of the connections is lost, is there an obvious and observable difference in "something" that might be recognized by test equipment connected to the PCB?

Comment: @ThePhoton sensor will not excite anything to the PCB. And also in every bonds of the PCB and the dice part, they are already connected to components/ground.

Comment: @Andyaka There is no test equipment connected to the PCB. In fact, that's perhaps what I want to do. However, the bond connection of all the wires are protected with epoxy capsulation.

Comment: Basically, this whole tile with connection between sensor and PCB is already doing what it is supposed to be doing.
What I want to do is just somekind of quality testing, as it is already investigated before, that after cycling for sometime, 1 or more wire connection will be gone.
And what I want to investigate now is, where those connections are lost.

Comment: If you can't tell us any more about your sensor and/or the circuit on the PCB, all I can recommend is chemically removing the epoxy and visually inspecting the wires.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think my question was a bit confusing, and you didn't get the idea of what I want to do. I've edited the question and I hope it is more clear to understand

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: You __must__ tell us something about the circuit that each bond wire is attached to. Without that information we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no one simple answer.  You must find a way to test each pin and that means connecting the device pins and testing in turn.  Check with the manufacturer and see if they can tell you what the functionality is of each pin, specifically is there are ESD structures on chip.  For all the pins that do have ESD (and likely all of them do, but it is possible that some do not have ESD protection) with all power rails shorted to ground, drive each pin negative with a weak driver (limited to a few mA drive or perhaps 10 mA drive).  If the wore bond has opened then the voltage will track, if the wire bond is connected you will not be able to drive below about -0.8 V.  You are using the ESD and parasitic Diodes (NWell to substrate etc.) to test the connection.

This presumes a lot of (albeit likely) things about how the sensor is fabricated, which may not be valid.  But probing the pins gently should allow you to characterize the pins and thus the connection.

Comment: Good answer for a overly broad question.  There are still some possible problems for OP, for example if some of the bondwires are in parallel with each other?